# Non-manual solution to "cannot remove prior installation of package" when re-installing R packages

Tags: r

I recently began receiving warnings that prior installations of R packages cannot be removed when I try to re-install packages:

```r
install.packages("gtools")
#> Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘gtools’
#> Warning: restored ‘gtools’
```

I found solutions to this issue encouraging me to delete the packages manually from my library folder, which I could find with `.libPaths()`. However, (a) this seems like a way of addressing symptoms rather than the underlying issue (which remains unclear) and (b) there are two paths for seemingly different versions of R and I'm not sure which to delete from anyway:

```r
.libPaths()           
#> [1] "C:/Users/foo/Documents/R/win-library/4.1"
#> [2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library"
```

How can I fix the problem so I don't have to manually delete package folders every time I want to re-install a package? If there is no alternative, do I need to delete the subdirectories for the package from one of those folders or both? FWIW, I'm working in RStudio.

Comment: Restart `R` or unload the package with `detach("package:gtools", unload=TRUE)` (in current `R` or other open `R` sessions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have installed packages using different permissions.  On Windows, you need elevated permissions to write to `Program Files`.  At some point you (or an admin) probably used "Run as admin" to install `gtools` there, and now using regular permissions you can't delete that.

You should be able to delete the `Users/foo` copy, if you are running as user `foo`, but even that one may have had permissions changed.  But I'd guess the issue is that `gtools` is in the `Program files` location.

The error message from R doesn't tell you which location it is trying to delete from, which is unfortunate.  In fact, allowing installations of different versions in those two locations is a bad design feature in R that just leads to confusion, because you don't necessarily always use the same version each time you load packages.  (The rule for which one you use is the first acceptable one found in the `.libPaths` list, but since you can change `.libPaths`, and since packages can load other packages, it's hard to predict which one you'll have loaded at any given time.)

To fix this, you can delete both copies (if you have two) and start over, but that's risky because other packages might be depending on `gtools`.  If you are the only user on your computer, you could instead delete the entire `"C:/Users/foo/Documents/R/win-library/4.1"` library, and then do all your installs using "Run as admin", but that's also easy to mess up.

(On a Mac, that's effectively what happens, because most single user systems put the user in the "admin" group, so they can always install packages to the system location.  It causes a lot less confusion, but some "purists" think the Windows way is better.)

So I don't have any good advice for you, but maybe this explains the situation, and you can work out for yourself the best way forward.

Comment: If I do all of my installs using run as admin, will I need to run as admin in the future to *update* / reinstall? Or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, you need to run as admin to make any changes to the `Program Files` library.  If you forget, R will "helpfully" create a new user library for you, and you'll be back in the current situation.

Comment: If "vice versa" means never using Run as admin, then I think the answer is "yes, you're better off", but you have to start with a nearly empty `Program Files` library.  You appear to already have `gtools` there, and probably have a lot of other packages too.  The only ones that really need to be there are the "base" packages, i.e. base    compiler    datasets    graphics   grDevices        grid     methods    parallel     splines    stats      stats4       tcltk       tools       utils.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. The only remaining confusion is why the versioning of the directories above differs (4.1 vs 4.1.2) but that's not directly related to the question.

Comment: Generally contributed packages built for any 4.1.x version will work with any 4.1.y version of R (though occasionally they may depend on bug fixes), so user libraries only need to match the 4.1.  But the `Program Files` dir was installed with R itself, and base packages will only work with that specific version.